# Scatter plot random numbers with two conditions (plot will look like a fuzzy circle with a square hole inside)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter, multiple-conditions

i am a new user programming in python who needs some help to complete one exercise.
before i generate 2000 random numbers between -10 and 10 for x and y, i need to make sure the x and y that dont fulfill these two requirements are out:
np.sqrt(x^2 + y^2) < 10
and when the absolute values for x and y are > 5.
how can i insert these two conditions on the plot ?

conditions:

```
np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) < 10
abs(x),abs(y) > 5
```

i start like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=2000
x = np.random.uniform(-10,10,N)
y = np.random.uniform(-10,10,N)

a = np.zeros(np.size(x), dtype=bool)
b = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

for i in range(np.size(x)):
    if (b[i] < 10):
        a[i] = True
x = x[a]
y = y[a]

plt.plot(x,y, "b o")
plt.show()
```

thank you very much in advance!

this is the edited code above, but i am still need to fulfill the condition where x and y is higher than 5 and -5

Comment: How these two requirements can hold together? if abs(x) and abs(y) are bigger than 5, then np.square(x**2 + y**2) > 10.

Comment: i think for x and y that are in the range of -5 and 5. and that satisfy the np.sqrt(x2+y2) i wanted to find a solution using the numpy as np. i think it is not that difficult but i am having difficult implementing this conditions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=2000
x = np.random.uniform(-10,10,N)
y = np.random.uniform(-10,10,N)

a = np.zeros(np.size(x), dtype=bool)
b = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

for i in range(np.size(x)):
    if (max(abs(x[i]), abs(y[i]))>5) & (b[i] < 10):
        a[i] = True
    else:
        a[i] = False
x = x[a]
y = y[a]

plt.plot(x,y, "b o")
plt.show()
```

[should look like this!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKnF0.png)

Thanks everyone ! i found the error

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code would be

```
var maxpoints = 2000
var ptx[maxpoints]
var pty[maxpoints]

for (num = 0; num < maxpoints; num++) {  # 

    do {

        trialx = np.random.uniform(-10,10,N) # create a new x
        trialy = np.random.uniform(-10,10,N) # create a new y

    } while (! ((math.sqrt(trialx**2 + trialy**2) < 10) &&
                (math.abs(trialx) > 5 && math.abs(trialy) > 5)))

    ptx[num] = trialx        
    pty[num] = trialy

}
```

basically continue the inner while loop until you discover the next x and y which satisfies your restrictions ... the restrictions on creating a circle would naturally do a square-root(x^2 + y^2)  and not  square(x^2 + y^2) ... @Jan please clarify this and update your question

***update***   I taught myself some python to translate above into working code with a picture

```
from array import array
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle_radius = 10

maxpoints = 2000
ptx = np.zeros(maxpoints)
pty = np.zeros(maxpoints)

seedval = circle_radius + 1

for num in range(0,maxpoints):

    trialx = seedval
    trialy = seedval

    while (not (((np.sqrt(trialx*trialx + trialy*trialy) < circle_radius)) and
                (np.abs(trialx) > 5 and np.abs(trialy) > 5))) :

        trialx = np.random.uniform(-circle_radius,circle_radius) # create a new x
        trialy = np.random.uniform(-circle_radius,circle_radius) # create a new y

        print "current trial ", trialx, trialy

    ptx[num] = trialx        
    pty[num] = trialy

    print num, trialx, trialy


plt.plot(ptx, pty, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

so above will generate this plot

[image]

Comment: thank you Scott, but this code didnt work on mine. and i am not familiar with var and trial x and y...

Comment: its pseudo-code which gives you the essence ... just take this approach and spin up some python

Comment: Yes, i meant square root.  probably this was one of my mistakes You are the man!